# Filter in sliced ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ui.bootstrap

I try make table with pagination and filter using angular. I found nice pagination example (of course I didn't "ctrl+c, ctrl+v), but I have one problem. I use `ng-repeat with slice` but if I would make `| filter` this doesn't work properly, because filtered items didn't change pages. For example  if item is on second page and I filter and is only one stiil stay on second page against go to first. Look on code and please help me make working filter

http://embed.plnkr.co/eheFSh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this case you should apply `filter` at first and only then pagination, i.e. `slice`:

```
name: <input type='text' ng-model='searchName'/>
id: <input type='text' ng-model='searchId'/>

<tr ng-repeat="row in (data | filter : {name:searchName, id: searchId }).slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage))">
     <td>{{row.name}}</td>
     <td>{{row.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, works good, but I would like filter row.name and row.id but separately. Now is searching in all rows name and id

Comment: @Mat.Now. It is not a problem, check out updated answer.